# Error in else if syntax? Can someone help find

Tags: c, if-statement, compilation, codeblocks

This won't compile, I get the error: expected identifier before ')' token message. This is a BMI calculator. Not sure where I went wrong with the syntax.

```
int main()
{

    int wtlb, htin, bmi;

    printf("Enter your weight lbs: ");
    scanf("%d", &wtlb);

    printf("Enter your height inches: ");
    scanf("%d", &htin);

    bmi = 703 * wtlb / pow(htin, 2);

    if (bmi < 18.5)
    {

        printf("Your bmi is underweight");

    }
    else if (bmi > 18.5) && (bmi < 24.9);
    {

        printf("Your bmi is normal")

    }
    else if (bmi > 25.0) && (bmi < 29.99)
    {

        printf("Your bmi is overweight");

    }
    else (bmi > 30.0)
    {

        printf("Your bmi is obese");

    }

    return 0;
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Extra semicolon, incorrect placement of parentheses. Voting to close as a typo.

Comment: Use `double` type for `bmi`, not `int`.

Comment: `else (bmi > 30.0)` --> `else` or `else if (bmi > 30.0)`

Comment: What happens in your code if the BMI is 29.995? Or exactly 18.5? etc.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the problem:

```
                // here ------------v
else if (bmi > 18.5) && (bmi < 24.9);
```

You have a stray semicolon at the end of the line.  Remove it.

Besides that, you need to enclose the entire expression in parenthesis to satisfy the `if` condition:

```
else if ((bmi > 18.5) && (bmi < 24.9))
```

Here as well:

```
else if ((bmi > 25.0) && (bmi < 29.99))
```

Comment: Note that SO suggests closing questions like that by providing a special reason - "unable to reproduce or a typo".

Comment: `else if ((bmi > 18.5) && (bmi < 24.9))` --> `else if ((bmi >= 18.5) && (bmi < 24.9))` or `else if (bmi < 24.9)` more better.